# How to efficiently deploy content types to a Content Type Hub

Tags: content-type, deployment, feature

I have set up a Content Type Hub and tested the syndication is working correctly by creating a test content type and watching it be published to the client site.

Then I deployed the content types I am actually interested in publishing to the hub (by way of a feature) along with the site columns they depend on.

I get the error:

`Content type '...' cannot be published to this site because feature '...' is not enabled.`

I want to deploy content types with features for upgradability and ease of porting between dev, qual and prod environments.  But am left not understanding what the benefit of the Hub is.

If I have to activate the deploying feature, the content types will already be on the site before publishing will take place.  If I have to manually create the content types on the Hub site with the web UI (yuck!), I have the issue of trying to keep three landscapes manually synchronized.

Is there a way to efficiently manage content type deployment to the Hub while still using the Hub to publish the content types?

Answer (score 1):

The benefit of the Hub is exactly what you are describing. It's a HUB where you deploy and manage all of your enterprise content types. Other Site collections subscribe to the content types from the hub and also subscribes on all the changes of the content types.

Your error above is due to the fact that you are deploying a content type to the hub that is dependant on another feature. For instance this is common if your deploying content types utilizing publishing features. You need to activate those features on the hub before deploying the content types - and you must also activate the features on the subscription site collections as well to get it working.

I wrote a post about this a couple of months back, check it out: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Plan-your-SharePoint-2010-Content-Type-Hub-carefully.aspx

Comment: I got the same error as above, but the "dependant feature" is my own CT feature provisioning the CTs to the hub.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Wictor.
But I am facing an issue with published content type's wsp.
I have activated all pre-requisite features and our content type hub publishing is working fine.
I created content type wsp,Deployed it as sandbox solution on content type hub site collection.Then published it to all subscribers.Now when I need to retract the wsp,I unpublish the content tyope and then retract.Still I can see the Published content types with its inherited site columns in the subscriber site collections..I am not able to delete the site columns from the content type through the GUI method as well...Is there any method to be included in the code to retract the published content types??We are actually stuck up since we are unable to retract the content types to make changes...

Answer (score -1):

Site columns and site content types that have been propagated from a content type hub are read-only.  You can go to their advanced properties and change that, if you have the right permissions.

Comment: this will be undone by the MetadataSubscriberTimerJob when it re-publishes content types